# jQuery - Avoid code repetition and shorten script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following line of jquery that targets each category item within my menu and moves the `li` to the first `ul.main_navigation_level_2`. The following works but I have to copy and paste it out 10 times for each different category.

```
$('li#main_navigation_dept_home_and_furniture_furniture ul.main_navigation_level_2')
  .children('li')
  .appendTo('li#main_navigation_dept_home_and_furniture_furniture ul.main_navigation_level_2:first');
```

The below is my attempt:

```
$(".main_navigation_level_2").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this);
    menuItem.children('li').appendTo(':first-child',this);
});
```

Comment: this question is better for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would you mind providing the relevant HTML you are working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be it

```
$(".main_navigation_level_2").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this);
    menuItem.children('li').appendTo(menuItem.first());
});
```

Comment: Why do you use  `menuItem.first()`  here. `menuItem`  is `$(this)`  and `this` is one `DOMElement` . So there is just one element in `menuItem`.

Comment: yes, `this` is  `DOMElement` but `$(this)` is a jQuery obj.

Comment: `$(this)`  creates a jQuery set only containing `this`. Then you call `.first()` on this result set. AS `[...]the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.` it will have no effect as the result set contains one element anyway. As of that it would be the same as writing `menuItem.children('li').appendTo( $(this) )` and because `appendTo` will also accept a `DOMElement` you could write `menuItem.children('li').appendTo( this )`,  without changing the result of your code.